# Conditional formatting: format based on another cell having ANY text

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need to write a conditional formatting formula that does the following:

Format J1 if J2 has any text at all.

Note: the text in J2 may be varied, so I can't use quotation marks. Is this type of formatting possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in the conditional formatting, write the condition as `=J2<>""`. This will be true if J2 contains *anything*, and false if it is blank.

I don't understand your issue with quotation marks - you can put quotation marks into J2, and it still works - `"` is not the same as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically interested in whether J1 has *text*, as opposed to a numerical value, you can use `istext`.

`=IsText(J1)`

HOW IT WORKS:

Umm...It checks to see if J1....is....text.